# What is the term for written expressions that lead to "reading between the lines?"

Tags: terminology

What is the term for something that is inferred, but not explicitly written within the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean subtext? Implication?

Comment: +1 @Dale Emery: Yes, appears subtext is the word I'm looking for, thank you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtext